# Pass headers in fabric Image.fromURL function

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js Image.fromURL function to load the image to canvas. For now, the images are loading successfully without any issues. But now I have a requirement to pass headers for authentication purposes is there a way that I could pass headers into the "Image.fromURL" function or any other way I could incorporate my headers to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image.fromUrl doesn't send a request. As you can see [here](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/src/shapes/image.class.js#L746) in source code this function uses `fabric.util.loadImage`, that as you can see [here](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/d61a34347af14a2f1d48831056308cb2abb14cc8/src/util/misc.js#L338) creates an image and set `src` attribute. Thus the browser makes the request for getting the image itself. And you cannot send your own headers using Image.FromURL function

I think you can get your images something like this (it's just idea):

```js
const image = new Image();
image.onload = () => {
  const fabricImage = new fabric.Image(image);
  canvas.add(fabricImage);
}

fetch("https://your-url", {headers: {}}).then((res)=>{
  image.src = res;
})
```